# How can I calculate the average rainfall from a HTML form?

Tags: php, html

I have a form where users input rainfall for 7 days. So to calculate the average rainfall from all 7 inputs, I made an array and put all the variables inside one. Have I done something wrong? How could I fix it to calculate average? Thank you

PHP code:

```
$rainfall = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6 ); 
     
$rainf_array = explode(',' , $rainfall);
$tot_rainf = 0; 
$rainf_array_length = count($rainf_array);
    
foreach($rainf_array as $rain){
    $tot_rainf += $rainf;
}
$avg_rainf = $tot_rainf/$rainf_array_length;
    
echo "Average Rainfall is : ".$avg_rainf."";
```

Comment: `$rainfall` is an array of the rainfall figures, so the `$rainf_array` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do `explode(',' , $rainfall)`. `explode()` is used to split a string by a separator and returns an array. You already have an array, so that' unnecessary.

Try:

```
$rainf_array = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6 ); 
$tot_rainf = 0; 
$rainf_array_length = count($rainf_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
$rainfall = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6 ); 
 
$avg_rainf = array_sum($rainfall) / count($rainfall);
echo echo "Average Rainfall is : " . $avg_rainf;
```

Answer (score 0):

explode() function is used to split a string, you're using an array so you don't have to use explode() function. Other than your code is fine.